# Downcasting a Rc<RefCell<Box<struct>>> to Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn trait>>>

Tags: rust, dynamic

I have the following struct.
It is just a wrapper for a vector of a given data type `T`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Port<T: 'static + Copy + Debug> {
    pub name: String,
    values: Vec<T>,
}
```

This structure implements the trait `PortTrait`.
On the other hand, I have the following structure

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Component {
    pub name: String,
    ports: HashMap<String, Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn PortTrait>>>>,
}
```

Components *share* ports to communicate. I want to use a method to i) create a new port `Port<T>`, ii) add this new port to the component, and iii) return a pointer to the newly created port.
So far, I got this:

```rust
impl Component {
    fn add_in_port<T: 'static + Copy + Debug>(&mut self, port_name: &str) -> RcCell<Box<Port<T>>> {
        let port = RcCell::new(Box::new(Port::<T>::new(port_name)));
        let x: RcCell<Box<dyn PortTrait>> = RcCell::clone(&port); // this fails
        self.ports.insert(port_name.to_string(), x);
        port
    }
}
```

This fails in compilation time when trying to *downcast* the clone of the port to a `dyn PortInterface`.

Do you know any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `Box`.

The problem is that we allocated `Rc<RefCell<Box<Port<T>>>>`. `Box<Port<T>>` has a size of 1 `usize`, but now you want to convert it to `Box<dyn PortTrait>` which has size of 2 `usize`s - but there is no place in the `Rc` to store it!

Luckily, you don't need `Box`: `Rc<RefCell<dyn Trait>>` works just fine.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Component {
    pub name: String,
    ports: HashMap<String, Rc<RefCell<dyn PortTrait>>>,
}

impl Component {
    fn add_in_port<T: 'static + Copy + Debug>(&mut self, port_name: &str) -> Rc<RefCell<Port<T>>> {
        let port = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Port::<T>::new(port_name)));
        let x = Rc::clone(&port) as Rc<RefCell<dyn PortTrait>>;
        self.ports.insert(port_name.to_string(), x);
        port
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f66a1445b3ede7ce2f4f8bc2d7541ecc).